# Win 10 Toast Notifications not staying in action center

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-10, toast

I created a WPF-Project in VS 2015 and I was able to include references to the Win 10 libraries. I created a test button which successfully creates and shows a toast notification. The problem is after the 5 seconds of showtime the toast disappears and doesn't get moved to the action center, it just vanishes. Anyone knows why?

Comment: Are you closing your application after showing the notification? Notifications disappear if created application is no longer running.

Comment: @user5226582 No I never closed the app when getting the toast.